# Flet App Virtual Keyboard project problems

Tags: python, flutter, flet

Please anyone tell me,

How to check which **Textfield** is **selected** or **focused** in Python **Flet** App?

I am making a **Keyboard** in **Flet** app and want to type **only** through it.
I am working on a Billing Software and want to add virtual keyboard for typing and normal keyboard also.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.